# WPF - Is changing binding expression from one to another may cause to memory leak?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, memory-leaks

Two questions:

1. Is it possible to cause a memory leak if I replace a `Binding` in a `Trigger`? For example, if my `Text` property bound to some dependency property, and in a trigger I set a *different* binding on `Text`, like in the example below, is there a chance for a leak?

   ```xml
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text={Binding PropertyX} />
     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
         <Setter TargetName="myTextBlock"
                 Property="Text"
                 Value="{Binding PropertyX, StringFormat={}{0} is too damn high}"/>
       </DataTrigger>
     </DataTemplate.Triggers>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

   Maybe some kind of "abandoned" binding?  I know that if I bind to non-dependency property/object, then I'll have a leak, but will the scenario above cause a leak?
2. I read somewhere (and I can't find it right now) that there are scenarios where if you give to an element the property `x:Name` then you may cause to memory leak. What are those cases? I believe that naming my elements in my templates is totally OK.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to cause memory leak if I change the binding by trigger.

In general, there's no more potential for a leak than there would be with just a single binding.  That's not to say that a leak is *impossible*, but if you follow the best practices and make sure anything you bind to implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then you won't accidentally cause your binding source to be retained.  Binding expressions use weak references to refer to the bound object, so that won't cause a leak.

Specifically, the example you posted looks fine, and should not cause a leak.

> I read somewhere (and I can't find it right now) that there are scenarios where if you give to an element the property x:Name then you may cause to memory leak.

The case would be when you *remove* an element with an `x:Name` directive from your UI tree.  The reason is that `x:Name` doesn't just set the `Name` property; it also registers the element in the *name scope*, and that registration involves a strong reference.  If you remove a named element from the UI *without* also removing it from the name scope, then it will be kept alive until the name scope becomes unreachable.

When removing a named element, call `UnregisterName` in the parent view, passing in the name of the element you are removing.  That will remove it from the name scope.